# how to customize return table snapshot by hibernate en verse query

Tags: spring-data, hibernate-envers

i am try with hibernate enverse below example code.

```
List personsAtAddress = getAuditReader().createQuery()
  .forRevisionsOfEntity(MyEntity.class, false, true)
```

getting the out put as jsen format as below

```
[ {"id"=1,
   "name" ="ssss"
  },{
     "revid" =1,
      "username" ="kkk"
  },
MOD
]
```

but my expected output is

```
["my entity" {"id"=1,
   "name" ="ssss"
  },
 "custom Revision Tale"{
     "revid" =1,
      "username" ="kkk"
  },
"modflag"="MOD"
]
```

how to get this result by a audit query in hibernate enverse

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to marshal the returned `Object[]` array from the Envers API to a `Map` using the keys your output expects to get the results.

```
final List<Map<String,Object> output = new ArrayList<>();
final List<Object[]> results = // this is the list of object arrays from Envers

for ( Object[] row : results ) {
  final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put( "my entity", row[0] );
  map.put( "custom Revision Tale", row[1] );
  map.put( "modflag", row[2] );
  output.add( map );
}
```